# System.LimitException: Too many future calls: 51

Tags: trigger, data-loader

We have an DataLoad activity.Query users where KCS Role /= null For any users that Knowledge License / TRUE.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you tell me if  FlexeraMemberCreationHandler.FlexeraMemberCreation is a future method?

Comment: @TSmith Thanks for your Quick Reply...Yes as per my understanding  FlexeraMemberCreationHandler is the Future method.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce imposes a governor limit that states no more than 50 future calls may be made in a single request. Take a look at the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm). The governor limit is not about 51 records being called/processed inside a future call, it's about the number of future calls in a single request. In your case here you are calling the future method for each user.

```
....
for(User u:trigger.new){
    if(u.Synchronize_with_Flexera_Member__c == true && !system.isbatch() && !system.isfuture() && !system.isScheduled()){
        FlexeraMemberCreationHandler.FlexeraMemberCreation(u.id); 
    }
}  
....
```

You will need to modify your future method to accept a list of these user ids and call once from your UserMasterTrigger. You will end up with something like the following in UserMasterTrigger after modifying FlexeraMemberCreationHandler.FlexeraMemberCreation method:

```
List<Id> userIds =  new List<Id>();
for(User u:trigger.new){
    if(u.Synchronize_with_Flexera_Member__c == true && !system.isbatch() && !system.isfuture() && !system.isScheduled()){
        userIds.add(u.Id);
    }
} 
if (userIds != null) FlexeraMemberCreationHandler.FlexeraMemberCreation(userIds);
```

Comment: Hi Smith,  Am sorry i didn't get your answer. We are tried your logic which you are mentioned above.But we are getting error like "Incompatible element type User for collection of Id at line 11 column 13 
" Please check below bit of code.  for(User u:trigger.new){if(u.Synchronize_with_Flexera_Member__c == true && !system.isbatch() && !system.isfuture() && !system.isScheduled()){
 userIds.add(u);
   //FlexeraMemberCreationHandler.FlexeraMemberCreation(u.id); 
            }
        }
            if (userIds!=null) FlexeraMemberCreationHandler.FlexeraMemberCreation(userIds);
    }

Comment: Pass the User Id to the userIds list.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just use dataloader.io and set it to 'Batch API' restricting to X number of requests? I came up with this issue and found this to work.